# MySQL : double IN() statement

Tags: mysql, sql

```
driver [ dcode, dname ]
route [ rcode, departure,arrival ]
ride [ dcode, rcode ]

SELECT dname FROM driver WHERE dcode IN (
   SELECT dcode FROM ride WHERE rcode IN (
       SELECT rcode FROM route WHERE departure = 'Barcelona' AND arrival = 'Madrid'
   ) AND
   rcode IN (
       SELECT rcode FROM route WHERE departure = 'Madrid' AND arrival= 'Barcelona'
   )
);
```

It's about a driver who makes both routes : Madrid-Barcelona and Barcelona-Madrid, but my query doesn't work.

Comment: Does your query cause an error or does it return no results? I assume the there are multiple routes with the same rcode that should be returning.

Answer (score 2):

Your inner query (2nd lvl) returns no results, because there can exist no `rcode`, which can be in the first subset (B->M) AND in the second(M->B). Please try this:

```
SELECT dname FROM driver WHERE dcode in
(SELECT dcode 
 FROM ride JOIN route
 ON (ride.rcode=route.rcode)
 WHERE route.departure = 'Barcelona' AND route.arrival = 'Madrid'
) AND dcode in (
 SELECT dcode 
 FROM ride JOIN route
 ON (ride.rcode=route.rcode)
 WHERE route.departure = 'Madrid' AND route.arrival = 'Barcelona'
)
```

Comment: Just a small correction: conditions on only one of the tables in a statement involving `join` clause should be in a `where` clause and not in the `on` clause. This may seem like nitpicking but it makes the query a lot more readable as the sql code convey the meaning better.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, Zohar, i applied in my edit...but is it really "just readability"!?? (I find myself often "misusing" the "on" clause as a "where" clause... feels like a question evolves:)

Comment: I don't know if it's going to effect the query's performance in any way, but this can be tested very easily by comparing execution plans on queries that are identical other then this particular change. In any case, code readability is not something to be taken lightly. Always think about the poor bastard that will have to do the maintenance work on your code 18 months from now. There's a high chance that poor bastard is going to be you :-)

Answer (score 2):

`where in` is the wrong approach, what you're looking for is `where exists`

```
SELECT dname FROM driver WHERE exists
  ( select dcode from route inner join ride on route.rcode = ride.rcode
     where departure = 'Barcelona' and arrival = 'Madrid' and ride.dcode = driver.dcode
  )
  and exists
  ( select dcode from route inner join ride on route.rcode = ride.rcode
     where departure = 'Madrid' and arrival = 'Barcelona' and ride.dcode = driver.dcode
  )
```

Alternatively, you can do it with no subqueries at all:

```
select dname 
  from driver d
    inner join ride r
      on d.dcode = r.dcode
    inner join route rr
      on r.rcode = rr.rcode
      and rr.departure = 'Barcelona'
      and rr.arrival = 'Madrid'
    inner join ride r2
      on d.dcode = r.dcode
    inner join route rr2
      on r2.rcode = rr2.rcode
      and rr2.departure = 'Madrid'
      and rr2.arrival = 'Barcelona';
```

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/086a4/22)

Comment: I think "wrong approach", is not the "complete truth", but very nice(correct) queries & demo! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

I think the the approach you are taking is:

1. Get the `dcode` for drivers on route Barcelona to Madrid. Let's call it *Set1*.
2. Get the `dcode` for drivers on route Madrid to Barcelona. Let's call it *Set2*.
3. Finally, get the `dname` for drivers whose `dcode` is in both *Set1* and *Set2*.

Your query for *Set1* is:

```
SELECT dcode FROM ride WHERE rcode IN (
   SELECT rcode FROM route WHERE departure = 'Barcelona' AND arrival = 'Madrid'
)
```

On the same lines the query for *Set2* would be:

```
SELECT dcode FROM ride WHERE rcode IN (
   SELECT rcode FROM route WHERE departure = 'Madrid' AND arrival = 'Barcelona'
)
```

Finally, you need to get `dcode`that's **in** *Set1* & **in** *Set2*. This would translate to the query:

```
SELECT dname FROM driver WHERE 
dcode IN (
   SELECT dcode FROM ride WHERE rcode IN (
      SELECT rcode FROM route WHERE departure = 'Barcelona' AND arrival = 'Madrid'
   )
)
AND 
dcode IN (
   SELECT dcode FROM ride WHERE rcode IN (
      SELECT rcode FROM route WHERE departure = 'Madrid' AND arrival = 'Barcelona'
   )
)
```

In your query, instead of looking for `dcode` in two sets, you were looking `rcode` in two sets.

Improvement suggestion: For the queries to get `dcode` sets, you could use *inner join* instead of using nested queries. Ex.:

```
SELECT dcode FROM ride INNER JOIN route ON ride.rcode = route.rcode 
WHERE departure = 'Barcelona' AND arrival = 'Madrid'
```

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't that be

```
    SELECT dname FROM driver WHERE dcode IN (
    SELECT dcode FROM ride WHERE rcode IN (
        SELECT rcode FROM route WHERE departure = 'Barcelona' AND arrival =    
'Madrid'
     ) OR
   rcode IN (
       SELECT rcode FROM route WHERE departure = 'Madrid' AND arrival= 'Barcelona'
   )
);
```

`OR` instead of `AND` ... ?

Comment: I think it depends on how the data is structured since the requirement is that the driver makes both routes, not just one of the two routes.

Comment: @hines yes, but if there's only one route, madrid-barcelona and the "return" is missing, you will get no result or probably an error since the list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The only scenario I can think of where `IN` doesn't return results where it should, is when there is `NULL` rcode in your table. Try using the following query

```
SELECT dname FROM driver WHERE dcode IN (
SELECT dcode FROM ride WHERE rcode IN (
   SELECT rcode FROM route WHERE departure = 'Barcelona'
   AND arrival =    'Madrid' AND rcode IS NOT NULL
) AND
rcode IN (
   SELECT rcode FROM route WHERE departure = 'Madrid' 
   AND arrival=  'Barcelona' AND rcode IS NOT NULL
 )
 );
```